# Error in unlocking bootloader in xperia ray with testpoint method

Tags: bootloader-lock, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

I was following guide to unlock my bootloader while preserving DRM data.

http://androidflip.com/unlock-xperia-phones-bootloader-without-losing-drm-data-track-id-working/

Everything went fine except the last one. Here is the log

I did all the steps in guide and receiving error for my xperia ray :crying:

Here is the log

```
Welcome to S1 tool.
That is small and crippled subset of SETOOL2 service tool.

DETACH USB CABLE FROM PHONE
REMOVE BATTERY FROM PHONE
ATTACH TESTPOINT
PRESS "READY", THEN ATTACH USB CABLE TO PHONE

PROCESSING ...
REMOVE TESTPOINT NOW, THEN PRESS "READY"

qcReceivePacket: can't get packet start.
Elapsed:24 secs.
```

Couldn't find a suitable answer in google. Any help?

Infos:

```
Boot loader unlock allowed : Yes
Build date 12W23
Can go to flash mode.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently xperia phones with newer EROM, bootloaders can't be unlocked via the above mentioned test point method.

Got the information from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=30675295&postcount=108